# Change IP address on the port script

Tags: powershell

I need a script to change the IP address on all Windows 7 pro X64 PC.

- If the first 2 match 192.168 then change
- If IP already change then ignore and move onto next ip/PC.
- Some PC will have more then 1 port.

I have try this which works but when you run it next time it keep adding the ip address.

```
$site = @{
    Site1 = 2;
    site2 = 3;
}
$site = $site.Values

$oldRange = "192.168."

foreach ($s in $site) {
    $ipAddress = $oldRange + $s + ".*"
    $printer = wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport get hostaddress
    $printer = $printer.Split('',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    if ($printer) {
        foreach ($p in $printer) {
            $OldIP = $p
            $OldIP2 = $OldIP -replace $oldRange, ""
            $old = [bool]($OldIP -as [IPAddress])
            if ($old) {
                $NewIP = "172.15.$OldIP2"
                $NewIP
                wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport where "hostaddress = '$OldIP'" set hostaddress="$NewIP"
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "None Found"
    }
}
```

Comment: `-replace` uses Regular Expression matching. Since your `$OldRange` has dots, you should escape these using `$oldRange = [Regex]::Escape("192.168.")`

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. Can you give more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done.

if anyone has better solution then please let me know

```
Clear-Host

$site = @{
    Site1=2;
    Site2=3;
}
$site =$site.Values

$oldRange = "172.11."

foreach($s in $site)
{

    $printer = wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport get hostaddress
    $printer=$printer.Split('',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    if($printer)
    {
        foreach ($p in $printer)
        {
            $OldIP = $p
            $OldIP2 = $OldIP -replace $oldRange, ""
            $old = [bool]($OldIP -as [IPAddress])
            if($old)
            {
                $sep = $OldIP.lastindexof(".") 
                $network = $OldIP.substring(0,$sep) 
                if("10.11."+$s -ne $network)
                {
                    $NewIP = "10.11.$OldIP2"
                    $NewIP
                    wmic path win32_tcpipprinterport where "hostaddress = '$OldIP'" set hostaddress="$NewIP"
                }else{
                    Write-Host "IP Already Changed"
                }
            }else
            {
                Write-Host "Not a IP address"
            }
        }
    }else{
        Write-Host "None Found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does lastIndexOf give you the right position? Looks like you want to cut 2 digits off?

Comment: lastIndexOf removes the last 3 numbers so it gives me e.g. 192.168.111 or 192.168.1

Comment: Ah ok, it wants the ‚site‘ included, yes ok.